# python: Why it tzinfo of datetime.now() none?

Tags: python

My timezone is not UTC. When I get the date time with `datetime.now()` I get the local time, but the `tzinfo` field has the value `none`.

I see the same result with python 2.7 and python 3.6.7.

I would expect to get a timezone info or a time offset value. Why is that ? Is there a way to get the time offset as needed for the ISO time format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `now` will get the present time of any particular timezone, by default it will give you the datetime object of current timezone that you're in (or your computer is set to).

You can get the present time of any other timezone, by passing that timezone to `now` function.

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: import pytz  # 3rd party: $ pip install pytz

In [4]: datetime.now()
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 12, 20, 10, 2, 778532)

In [5]: datetime.now(pytz.utc)
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 12, 14, 40, 4, 334078, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```